# Alternate series $(-5)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve Problem $1.14$ from Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by Mary L. Boas:

> A computer program gives the result $1/6$ for the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-5)^n$. Show that this series is divergent. Do yo see what happened? *Warning hint:* Always consider whether an answer is reasonable, whether it's a computer answer or your work by hand.

The book has not introduced the concept of alternating series. Only relevant equation is $S_n = a/(1-r)$. When I use this equation I get $5/6$ (not $1/6$ as the book suggests).

$1$) When should a student be aware not to use this equation?

$2$) Where is the logical flaw in using the equation $S_n = a/(1-r)$? Even though this is a geometric series and $r<1$?

Comment: Please don't link images when it is reasonably possible to type them, as in this case.  Images can't be browsed.  You need $|r|<1,$ not $r<1.$

Comment: When "wrongly using the formula" you have $a=(-5)^0 = 1$ and $r = -5$, which indeed yields $1/6$. How did you get $5/6$?

Comment: @ClementC. I wrongly divided 1st term by 2nd term to obtain r (r = -1/5). It's 2nd term by 1st term (r  = -5/1). So, that's where I messed up.

Comment: @user3709772 That makes sense. Well, that at least is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The formula
$$
a+ar+ar^2\dotsb=\frac{a}{1-r}
$$
is true for $|r|<1$. If $|r|\geq 1$, the terms of the series don't go to zero and hence the series does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-5)^n\neq0$ so the series must diverge. I think computer gives answer $\frac 16$, because it uses equation you mentioned (for $r = -5$ it gets $\frac1{1-(-5)}=\frac16$).

Comment: We aren't talking about the sequence $a_n = (-5)^n$. The question is about $\sum_{n\to \infty} (-5)^n$.

Comment: The formula does not apply in this case.

Comment: Yeah, but If $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{n}\neq 0$ or if the limit does not exist, then $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}$  diverges.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n(-5)^n$ does not converge as the terms in the series do not converge to 0.

One should always use the Divergence Test to see whether you should even proceed. Be careful. Just because the terms go to 0 does NOT imply that the series converges.